# Functor not working

Tags: c++

```
struct Person
{
string Name = "Unknown";

typedef pair<string, string> Trait;
vector<Trait> Traits;
};


bool HasTrait(vector<Person::Trait> & traits, Person::Trait & soughtTrait)
{
return find_if(traits.begin(), traits.end(), 
    [soughtTrait] (Person::Trait & trait)
    {
        return StringEquals(soughtTrait.first, trait.first) && StringEquals(soughtTrait.second, trait.second);
    })
    != traits.end();
}

Person FindMatchingPersonByRawTraits(string rawTraits)
{
    Person soughtPerson;

    vector<string> traits = split(rawTraits, ' ');
    for(string trait : traits)
    {
        vector<string> keyValuePair = split(trait, '=');

        string key = keyValuePair[0];
        string value = keyValuePair[1];

        soughtPerson.Traits.push_back(make_pair(key, value));
    }

    for(Person & person : mPersons)
    {
        for (auto & soughtTrait : soughtPerson.Traits)
        {
            if (HasTrait(person.Traits, soughtTrait))
            {
                return person;
            }
        }
    }

    static Person unknownPerson;
    return unknownPerson;
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem with Functor here as it should find the pair inside a vector but the problem is every time no matter what trait I provide the result is always unknown.

I cannot understand whether the problem is in storing data or retrieving it but I guess it's in the way the functor is written.

`std::vector<Person> mPersons;` is the vector of all persons those are acknowledged.

`rawTraits` are supplied as `Age=20 Sex=Man`

**EDIT FOR QUESTION**
Simplifying it introduced a map in place of vector of pairsnow how can i search if on map has the values of other maps

```
for(Person & person : mPersons)
        {
            for (auto & soughtTrait : soughtPerson.Traits)
            {
                //Check wether key value pairs in soughtPerson.Traits are present in person.Traits
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your example is a little to minimal.  Can you supply a complete [mcve]?

Comment: What else is expected @NathanOliver

Comment: The contents of `rawTraits` would be helpful.  Also `split()`.  Basically give me something I can copy and paste into my compile and hit go.

Comment: Sure, added it in the edit. Split simple splits the string from the space character as it does in python

Comment: What's `StringEquals` and why aren't you using `==`? Anyway, you should be deserializing the Trait string into actual objects and provide a comparator for them, that would be much more readable.

Comment: Oh yes ! @BartekBanachewicz thats helpful, i'll update the same

Comment: But that's not the problem @BartekBanachewicz

Comment: It's not a problem directly, but the bad design makes it more error-prone. The next thing you could do would be to change your container to `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, which would give you a much neater lookup.

Comment: Of course yes, design will be changed but the thing should be working at first

Comment: I think the problem is with HasTrait but could not figure out myself